# How to disable Google Cast on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I have this problem whenever playing a youtube video. There's always another background video/audio that's playing alongside my main video. Initially I didn't know where this sound come from because I didn't do anything. But then I realized this top right button, I clicked it and I saw that there's another random video playing.

[image]

It's really annoying that this video just come out of nowhere and playing in the background. It is not a Google Chrome Extension / Plugin, I have tried right click but this is what it shows. I have checked my Extensions and it's not there.

[image]

[image]

To be honest, I'm not sure what the name of that feature. I can see upon right click it says "Report an Issue with Google Cast" but when I googled a Google Cast icon is different from this one.

**Please help, how to disable this?**

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you activated Live captions in `chrome://settings/accessibility` settings, which led to activation of Global Media control.

Steps helped me to deactivate button:

1. Go to `chrome://settings/accessibility`, turn toggle off for `Live Caption`
2. Go to `chrome://flags/`, search for `#global-media-controls-cast-start-stop`, select `Disabled` from drop-down from the list on the right

P.S Global media control seems to be appearing again but now it is not behaving like before (it is almost like disabled, but pops up whenever i activate some sort of media)

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, Live Caption on your first step is already disabled, it's not the issue https://imgur.com/a/S1FYbaw

Comment: On your second step, it's currently selected as "default" I'll change it to Disabled and see how it goes in the next few days. https://imgur.com/a/DEacyzr

Comment: Confirmed, it doesn't work! The play thingy is still showing up... I'm gonna remove my extensions I am suspecting there's a malware in my extensions.